# Simple RSS Feed Can't Open Website

Tags: android, eclipse, rss

I'm doing a simple RSS Feed tutorial and unfortunately something went wrong.
Tutorial: http://www.cse.nd.edu/courses/cse40814/www/RSS_Android.pdf

(The more detailed tutorial is on a website whose bandwidth limit was reached.)

The code is almost identical, minus some variables I changed to make them easier for me to identify. I didn't copy and paste anything, so it's possible I could have made a mistake while typing, but I doubt it. The only thing my log tells me is that it can't open the test website.
Console recognizes no errors.

LogCat:

```
12-29 21:16:40.062: E/RssReader(614): Couldn't open http://www.southbendtribune.com/ws/content/collection/?collection=sbt_sports_photogalleries&key=d3IwcUN6Ym9NVEV0MWkzcEJsVEU2UFp3bWxmbVRzWFBxbVNyc0pjd1BOWjk4alBLSEpOdHRJVlhXK1dscWhvZg&version=1.0&limit=20
```

Main Activity:

```
package tutorials.baseRSSReader;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class StartMain extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.start_main);

    try {
        // Create RSS reader
        RssReader rssReader = new RssReader("http://www.southbendtribune.com/ws/content/collection/?collection=sbt_sports_photogalleries&key=d3IwcUN6Ym9NVEV0MWkzcEJsVEU2UFp3bWxmbVRzWFBxbVNyc0pjd1BOWjk4alBLSEpOdHRJVlhXK1dscWhvZg&version=1.0&limit=20");

        // Get a ListView from main view
        ListView Items = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        // Create a list adapter
        ArrayAdapter<RssItem> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<RssItem>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, rssReader.getItems());
        // Set list adapter for the ListView
        Items.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Set list view item click listener
        Items.setOnItemClickListener(new ListListener(rssReader.getItems(), this));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("RssReader", e.getMessage());
    }
    }
}
```

RssReader:

```
package tutorials.baseRSSReader;

import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

public class RssReader {

    private String rssURL;

    public RssReader(String rssURL)
    {
        this.rssURL = rssURL;
    }

    public List<RssItem> getItems() throws Exception {
        // SAX parse RSS data
        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();

        RssParseHandler handler = new RssParseHandler();

        saxParser.parse(rssURL, handler);

        return handler.getItems();

    }
}
```

I can list all of the code if needed but I think the error is somewhere in these two classes. I appreciate the help in advance.

EDIT:
The feed I was using wasn't valid, I am now using:http://rss.nytimes.com/services/xml/rss/nyt/HomePage.xml

And since I got a hold of an actual device, I'm getting one more error in the Log:

```
12-29 22:19:02.608: W/global(11470): [DNS] InetAddress.lookupHostByName NOT CACHED, so DNS Query
```

I do not see this in the emulator, though.

EDIT:
Refreshed the manifest, something was causing it to not recognize the permissions tag, but I'm not sure what...
I don't get the "couldn't open" error anymore, but now I'm trying to make sense of the Log...
There isn't anything on the AndDev website that covers lookupHostByName, but it seems to me that it can't find what it's looking for, perhaps the RSS Feed I'm using just doesn't work.
LogCat:

```
12-31 13:34:36.314: W/global(2805): [DNS] InetAddress.lookupHostByName NOT CACHED, So DNS Query
12-31 13:34:36.384: W/global(2805): [DNS] name(rss.nytimes.com), IN, AAAA, CNAME, TTL=4m16s
12-31 13:34:36.384: W/global(2805): [DNS] name(rss.nytimes.com), IN, AAAA, CNAME, TTL=11m44s
12-31 13:34:36.384: W/global(2805): [DNS] name(rss.nytimes.com), IN, A, CNAME, TTL=4m16s
12-31 13:34:36.384: W/global(2805): [DNS] name(rss.nytimes.com), IN, A, CNAME, TTL=11m44s
12-31 13:34:36.384: W/global(2805): [DNS] name(rss.nytimes.com), IN, A, A, TTL=50S
12-31 13:34:36.384: W/global(2805): [DNS] InetAddress.lookupHostByName ttl= 50
12-31 13:34:36.384: W/global(2805): [DNS] AddressCache.customTtl : ttlS= 50
12-31 13:34:36.645: W/global(2805): [DNS] InetAddress.lookupHostByName host = rss.nytimes.com => cached..
```

I think these refer to an error while parsing? I'm not sure.

Comment: Maybe try another URL first and see if that works? Google reader refused to add the URL you posted to my list of feeds, that may be a clue.

Comment: Something else of interest - a RSS feed validator: http://validator.w3.org/appc/

Comment: Thanks, the feed wasn't valid at all. That doesn't fix the problem though. I'm using a new valid feed, http://rss.nytimes.com/services/xml/rss/nyt/HomePage.xml, and it still gets the same error.

Comment: Do you have the internet permission added in your manifest?

Comment: Yes: <uses-permission android:name="android.permisson.INTERNET"/>

Comment: I have a vague feeling that this error is because of the abstruse internet configuration I'm using...

Comment: Try to open that feed from the browser on your device before you continue spending time on trouble-shooting it in your app. If it's your internet connection/configuration, it won't work in browser, either.

Comment: It works on the device... I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Okay, I removed the permission, saved it, and added it again... Now it still doesn't work but it isn't giving me any fatal errors, just a bunch of Log I'm trying to understand. I added it to the question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Started using a different tutorial, some of the code is invalid and outdated.